# Unable to deploy contract in quorum(truffle)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, quorum

was working with deploying contracts using truffle(truffle migrate) for manually created nodes as per "https://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/Getting-Started-From-Scratch/" (using raft-consensus) . I am able to add peer(other machine) and create network, but when i was deploying using truffle i am gettong the following errorError encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Error: Error: Returned error: authentication needed: password or unlock
   at Object.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-migrate/index.js:92:1)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of your question posted on Slack. I suggest avoiding multiple postings to avoid duplication of effort. For reference, here is the link to the Slack conversation:

https://go-quorum.slack.com/archives/C68NY0QQZ/p1562682519077000

(it may require Slack membership to view it).